# Add success message to category add screen

Tags: custom-taxonomy, customization

I have custom taxonomy named "Products", When i add new Product using "edit-tags.php", It is added using ajax. I want to show message after it is added, like "Product added successfully"!

When we edit taxonomy, we get message "item updated." But here page refreshes. I want same indication/message for when adding product.

is it even possible?

I would also like any js solution, if i can get a hook in js which is called after adding custom taxonomy.